# How to get simple Sum with JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, sum, jooq

What is the right way to get simple `sum` with JOOQ?

```
SELECT sum(PERSON.AGE) FROM PERSON;
```

I think about something like that:

```
BigDecimal sum = factory.select(sum(PERSON.AGE)).from(PERSON).fetch???;
```

?

Answer (score 3):

```
Record1<BigDecimal> record = factory.select(sum(PERSON.AGE)).from(PERSON).fetchOne();
BigDecimal decimal = record.getValue(record.field1());
```

If there are no records to sum, decimal will be null. This case will result in an error if you try ending with:

```
.fetchOneInto(Integer.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do:

```
// Static imports are assumed to be present:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Then use:

```
BigDecimal sumValue = factory.select(sum(PERSON.AGE)).from(PERSON).fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal sum = (BigDecimal) create.select( sum(PERSON.AGE).as("PERSON_AGE_SUM")) .from(PERSON);
```

Just try this ..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
BigDecimal sum = factory.select(sum(PERSON.AGE)).from(PERSON).fetchOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal sum = factory.select(PERSON.AGE.sum()).from(PERSON).fetchAnyInto(BigDecimal.class);
```